# How do I re-connect a missing lightroom folder?

Tags: lightroom

Due to space issues, I initially imported photos while still on a SD card.

After getting rid of all the unwanted shots, I then shut down Lightroom and moved my photos from the SD card onto my hard drive and removed the SD card.

I am now stuck in some kind of Lightroom purgatory where my original imported folder disappeared completely (since the drive was unmapped)  and when I try to re-import to a new folder, all the photos are marked as duplicates / disabled and LightRoom will not let me force a re-import.

I've been stuck with this for a while. I don't see any clear way to force LightRoom to let me import. it just keeps insisting it won't let me re-import because LightRoom knows best! :)

What's the best way to deal with this now? Is it possible to find the disconnected folder and re-map its source?

According to one article I should be able to do this:
 [image: screenshot of Find Missing Folder... context menu selection]

but I can't find the folder that was on a separate drive, and thus not on my list now.

Comment: Have you browsed to the folder your copied images live in on the other drive?

Comment: @CrazyDino it no longer exists since i moved it to my hard drive. even if i plug my sd card back in, the folder does not re-appear.

Comment: Point it to the folder containing the images on the hard drive? Lightrooms quite smart.

Comment: @CrazyDino there is nothing to point. 
when i browse to that folder in lightroom, all images are grayed out. 
i can try importing a new folder, and when i select new folder where the images are moved, everything is grayed out (including import button). LR thinks it's already imported.
LR is too smart for its own good

Comment: In which view did you try to find it? Library? Import?

Comment: Maybe you need to provide some SD card to geht a mapped drive. I don't know how this is done in Mac.

Comment: Sonic Soul i'm not talking about the import. Im talking about the finding missing folder. Click that. Navigate to the new directory where the images are now on your external hard disk. It doesnt matter if the location was the same or not, the contents don't even need to match. (so there could be more files in there then it's looking for)

Comment: @Gerhardh i tried in both! even after re-inserting the sd card. that folder just never re-surfaced..

Comment: As a workaround you might import a new image from SD Card. Then the folder must appear.

Comment: @Gerhardh that should work. only caveat is remembering what the folder name was as it's my camera creating them and not always the same :) but yah .. only thing is i didn't process that many images so it's less work for me to just re-import at this point. but good to know how that works

Comment: If you have an image in top folder, the missing subfolders in the library should be visible and can be moved/linked to valid locations. Apart from that: Take a lesson learned and never forget to move images from SD card to hard drive. You can also delete images from there afterwards.

Comment: @Gerhardh the problem is the card can have 20 gigs of images and i don't have that space on HD so i'd like to be able to load them up and prune 80% of stuff i don't need. I know there are many ways to do this, but I don't think it should be that difficult to do using Lightroom. Lessons learned :) 

would be nice if LR offered a way to do the physical file move for you all in one place.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution.

There is a `don't import duplicates` checkbox on the Import screen.

Unchecking it let me import the thing again. Although I realize that any changes I made on the previous folder will not be present on this import.

> as Gerhardh pointed out, best solution is to do whatever is necessary
>   to find original folder in the library and then move it's source file
>   location.

Comment: As everything ist gone, you should never ever import again. It is essential to find the folders for existing pictures.

Comment: @Gerhardh i have that a try for half hour.. unfortunately i'm not a socialite with unlimited time :) 
i can see how this is doable on my regular HD folders that were removed.. but not on sd card